# Does ingesting creatine powder or capsules cause hair loss?

Tags: supplement, hairloss, creatine

Does ingesting creatine powder or capsules cause hair loss?

I have read conflicting claims (e.g., see below) and wonder whether there have been some more serious scientific studies:

http://seannal.com/articles/supplementation/creatine-hair-loss.php ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170502021837/http://seannal.com/articles/supplementation/creatine-hair-loss.php)) is inconclusive:

> I personally don’t consider this one study to be a serious cause for alarm because of the points I mentioned above, but it’s up to you to weigh out the possibilities for yourself.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19741313 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170502023014/https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19741313)):

> Creatine supplementation may, in part, act through an increased rate of conversion of T to DHT. Further investigation is warranted as a result of the high frequency of individuals using creatine supplementation and the long-term safety of alterations in circulating androgen composition.

https://examine.com/nutrition/does-creatine-cause-baldness/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170502022448/https://examine.com/nutrition/does-creatine-cause-baldness/)):

> Creatine has been implicated once in increasing DHT. The study has not been replicated, and direct studies between creatine and hair loss have not been conducted

https://redd.it/1vfvdk ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170502023023/https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/1vfvdk/creatine_and_hair_loss/)):

> Short answer; maybe.

Comment: This is an area of active research and only time and more research will provide us with more substantial answers.